# How to decrement a list index in a loop

Tags: python, api, list, decrement

In my code below I am taking the split_message list and querying an API.  If there are no results, my next step would be to decrement the index of the list by -1, so I remove the last item from the list and retry the search.  If there are no results again, I would like to repeat the process until I receive results.

---

```
import requests
import json

message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"

split_message = message.split()

length = len(split_message)

def decrementList():
    initial_request = requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='+"%20"
                                   .join(split_message[:]))
    json_string = initial_request.content
    json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    num_results = json_dict['info']['num_results']
    if num_results == 0:
        print "Sorry, no match!"
    if num_results > 0:
        print "Result found!"

decrementList()
```

Effectively, my next step would be to take this:

```
requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='+"%20"
                                       .join(split_message[:]))
```

and turn it into this:

```
requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='+"%20"
                                       .join(split_message[:-1]))
```

and then this:

```
requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='+"%20"
                                       .join(split_message[:-2]))
```

And repeating until I get a match.

I can think of extremely non-pythonic ways to do this, but it seems like way too many if statements.  So what would be the best and most pythonic solution to what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's probably slow because you'd be making multiple web requests, not because of how you're handling your list.

Comment: slow was probably the wrong word to use. not really slow, just looking for a more pythonic way of doing this than 10 if statements. removing it from the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Actually, I like this version more. A bit cleaner IMHO.

```
def decrementList(words):
    words_remaining = words[:]
    while words_remaining:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + '%20'.join(words_remaining))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        if json_dict['info']['num_results'] > 0:
            num_words_taken = len(words) - len(words_remaining)
            return num_words_taken, json_dict

        words_remaining.pop()
```

Got the `list.pop` inspiration from @falsetru, see other answer.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Maybe this is more to your liking:

```
import requests
import json

message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"

split_message = message.split()

def decrementList(words):
    for w in [words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + "%20".join(w))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        num_results = json_dict['info']['num_results']
        if num_results > 0:
            num_removed = len(words) - len(w)
            return num_removed, json_dict

num_words_removed, json_dict = decrementList(split_message)
```

The key is `[words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]`. Assuming `words = message.split()`, you get the list

```
[
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out', 'of', 'my', 'mind'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out', 'of', 'my'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out', 'of'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let', 'it', 'go'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let', 'it'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can', 'let'],
    ['if', 'i', 'can'],
    ['if', 'i'],
    ['if']
]
```

Which I believe does what you want, and it's arguably 'Pythonic'. The function will break out of the loop as soon as you get the results you want. It returns both the number of words you had to remove from the list to get some results, as well as the JSON dict resulting from the request.

Comment: `[words[x:] for x in range(len(words))]` should be `[words[:x] for x in range(len(1, words))]`

Comment: why did you add num_words_removed, json_dict =  to the end?

Comment: Actually it should be `reversed([words[:x] for x in range(1, len(words))])`. Python will complain about `len(1, words)`, and also, it's in reverse of the order he's asking for.

Comment: @Barnaby I added `num_words_removed, json_dict = ...` to illustrate the cleanest way to get the return values of the function. The first is how many words were removed from the wordlist, and the second is the JSON result.

Comment: i did this instead of reversed `for w in [words[:-x] for x in range(len(words))]:` seems to work the same. do you agree?

Comment: The first element of that is an empty list, so you'll waste a query. This is because `words[:0]` is `[]`. However, `[words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]` **actually** actually works.

Comment: ahh okay, thanks. i will stick with the reverse then! thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Barnaby Actually, that has an off-by-one error, too. Use the example in my answer, I edited it! Then mark as the answer if you're happy with it. :)

Comment: i am certainly happy with it - thanks again. taught me a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Use [`list.pop`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types):

```
>>> message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"
>>> split_message = message.split()
>>> split_message.pop()
'mind'
>>> split_message
['if', 'i', "can't", 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out', 'of', 'my']
>>> split_message.pop()
'my'
>>> split_message
['if', 'i', "can't", 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out', 'of']
```

Comment: i don't want to remove the item from the list.  i need to keep the whole list intact for use later.  can i still use this method without doing that?

Comment: @Barnaby, How about making a copy? `copy = split_message[:]`

Comment: actually, another question.  i need to keep track of how many indices i delete from the list, so my next query starts where i left off.  as in. is this possible to do? i feel like list.pop() likely isn't the best solution

Comment: @Barnaby, `len(split_message) - len(copy)` will give you the number of items that were deleted.

Comment: i edited my post to show an implementation of what you are suggesting, but i can't get it to work and it just seems illogical to me

Comment: @Barnaby, Why do you repeat same code? Why don't you use loop?

Comment: what kind of loop are you referring to?

Comment: @Barnaby, `for i in range(len(split_message))` or `while copy`. BTW, you remove the code. never mind.